# Resize image using Picasso and add to HttpPost

Tags: java, android, http, picasso

What is the best way to resize an image using Picasso and upload it using HttpPost.

```
Bitmap bmp = Picasso.with(context)
                    .load(path)
                    .resize(1000, 1000)
                    .centerInside()
                    .onlyScaleDown()
                    .get();

MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity();
entity.addPart("image", new FileBody(file));
```

What's the best way (memory) to achieve this?

Clarification: now I'm doing

- Bitmap b = Picasso.resize().get();
- Create new file
- Write Bitmap b to file
- Include file in HttpPost

And I'm searching if there is a more efficient way

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in that way:

```java
Bitmap bmp = Picasso.with(context)
                .load(path)
                .resize(1000, 1000)
                .centerInside()
                .onlyScaleDown()
                .get();

ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);

HttpEntity entity = MultipartEntityBuilder.create()
        .addBinaryBody("image", new ByteArrayInputStream(stream.toByteArray()), ContentType.create("image/png"), "filename.png")
        .build();
```

BUT, as far as I know, Apache HttpClient is **deprecated** on Android and I recommend using the [OkHttp3](http://square.github.io/okhttp/) library to make HTTP requests.

Example:

```java
Bitmap bitmap = Picasso.with(context)
            .load(path)
            .resize(1000, 1000)
            .centerInside()
            .onlyScaleDown()
            .get();

ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);

RequestBody requestBody = new MultipartBody.Builder()
        .addFormDataPart("image", "filename.png", RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/png"), stream.toByteArray()))
        .build();

Request request = new Request.Builder()
        .url("https://example.com")
        .post(requestBody)
        .build();

OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
        // handle failure
    }

    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
        // handle server response
    }
});
```